# is it possible to create CRUD generator in codeigniter just like Yii and CakePHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, crud, grocery-crud

previously i worked on Yii framework but after my job change i have to work on codeigniter.but in Yii there is one helper/plugin like when you create database table and once you enter your table in one form and click OK button then it will generate CRUD operation automatically and it's controller,view,and models are created dynamically.I just want to know if that type of plugin available in codeigniter or what will require to finish that Plugin or helper.

Comment: Not build in, but there are some CRUD libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CRUDIgniter - Codeigniter code generator](http://crudigniter.com) is a free online tool to generate codeigniter CRUD code directly from the SQL schema.

It works by just uploading the SQL database file, choose from the form validation rules of codeigniter and finally you get an archive of the code which directly plugs into your application.

PS : I'm the founder of the CRUDIgniter project.

Comment: Hi @YD8877, CRUDIgniter is down from more tha an year can you please let us know when it'll be back

Answer (score 4):

Here is a REST Server that seems to be maintained.

https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

There is also GroceryCRUD if you want it in PHP still.

http://www.grocerycrud.com/